# update rows with incremental value

Tags: sql, postgresql

suppose I have a table in a postgresql database with columns: `time,speed`

Now I've added a column "`distance`" and I want to insert the values of distance by something like:

```
   row[time+1].distance = row[time].distance + row[time+1].speed
```

which is the fastest way to update the table?

**UPDATE**

I would like to try something like:

```
d = 0.0
for row in select time,speed from my_table loop
  d = d + row.speed
  update my_table set distance = d where time = row.time
end loop
```

is this the best way? How can I make this snippet run?

Comment: My physics is rusty, but shouldn't this be more like `distance + speed * time_diff`? (else, you're adding meters and meters/second, which isn't homogenic.)

Comment: Yes, it is like that... I don't wanted to mention the parameter time_diff, which, anyway is constant. While time is actually a count.

Comment: Is there many entries in you table ?

Comment: @ImaneFateh yes, a lot! If I take the sum of all the entries in the "speed" column it takes a second or so.

Comment: The real question is why do you think you need to update the table to have another row, when the value is so easy to calculate.

Comment: I want another column to cache the computation.

Comment: Well, for caching you could consider using virtual column based on function. But anyway - provided answer with solution.

Comment: Function based indexes: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-createindex.html psudeocolumns using immutable values.  If the overhead of the calculation is so great and the use of the column so frequent, this is generally the best way to go; as maintaining the code gets risky as someone could forget to do the calculation later. commonly used for upper/lower comparisons as such http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.3/static/indexes-functional.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I made a table:

```
create table whatever ( time_c int4, speed int4, distance int8);
```

and inserted some rows:

```
insert into whatever (time_c, speed) select i, random() * 100 from generate_series(1,10) i;
```

This gave me this data:

```
$ select * from whatever;
 time_c | speed | distance 
--------+-------+----------
      1 |    53 |   [null]
      2 |    17 |   [null]
      3 |    53 |   [null]
      4 |    46 |   [null]
      5 |    31 |   [null]
      6 |    18 |   [null]
      7 |    42 |   [null]
      8 |    15 |   [null]
      9 |     1 |   [null]
     10 |    51 |   [null]
(10 rows)
```

Then, I use `DO` command:

```
do $$
DECLARE
    tmp_cur cursor for SELECT * FROM whatever ORDER BY time_c for UPDATE;
    temprec record;
    total_distance INT4 := 0;
BEGIN
    open tmp_cur;
    LOOP
        fetch tmp_cur INTO temprec;
        EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
        total_distance := total_distance + temprec.speed;
        UPDATE whatever SET distance = total_distance WHERE CURRENT OF tmp_cur;
    END LOOP;
END;
$$;
```

And that's all:

```
$ select * from whatever;
 time_c | speed | distance 
--------+-------+----------
      1 |    53 |       53
      2 |    17 |       70
      3 |    53 |      123
      4 |    46 |      169
      5 |    31 |      200
      6 |    18 |      218
      7 |    42 |      260
      8 |    15 |      275
      9 |     1 |      276
     10 |    51 |      327
(10 rows)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works! I have one small problem: executing the same statement repeatedly, I get the error "DatabaseError: cursor "tmp_cur" already in use". How to fix it?

Comment: Hmm ... not sure what/how you're doing it, but when I run the do $$...$$ many times, I don't get any errors.

Comment: I'm executing the SQL code from python. I'm reusing the same connection and it gives the error on the second execution (no matter if I request a new cursor or reuse the same cursor).

Comment: The close is automatic after you finish the transaction.

Comment: Ok, in fact I want to execute it multiple times in the same transaction

Answer (score 1):

No need for a loop or even for storing this data. Apparently you want a "running sum" of the "speed" column, which can easily be done using a window function:

(Sample data shamelessly stolen from Depesz's answer)

```
create table whatever 
( 
   time_c int4, 
   speed int4, 
   distance int8
);

insert into whatever (time_c, speed)
values
( 1,53), 
( 2,17), 
( 3,53), 
( 4,46), 
( 5,31), 
( 6,18), 
( 7,42), 
( 8,15), 
( 9, 1), 
(10,51);

select time_c, 
       speed,
       sum(speed) over (order by time_c) as distance
from whatever 
order by time_c;
```

```
time_c | speed | distance
-------+-------+---------
1      | 53    | 53      
2      | 17    | 70      
3      | 53    | 123     
4      | 46    | 169     
5      | 31    | 200     
6      | 18    | 218     
7      | 42    | 260     
8      | 15    | 275     
9      | 1     | 276     
10     | 51    | 327
```

If you really want to store data that can easily be calculated, you can do that with a single update statement:

```
with derived_data as ( 
  select time_c, 
         speed,
         sum(speed) over (order by time_c) as distance
  from whatever 
)
update whatever 
  set distance = dd.distance
from derived_data dd
where dd.time_c = whatever.time_c;
```

This update assumes that `time_c` is a unique attribute in the table.

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/16332/2

Comment: Yes, this is for sure a cleaner solution. Also seems that postgresql is able to optimize the SUM over the window (reusing the previous computed sum), because this is as fast as the accepted solution!

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your comment, the easiest is to express row.distance as a sum of times * speed from preceding rows.

The select would look like this (use it to run a few checks):

```
select t1.id, sum (t1.speed * time_diff) as distance
from table t1 join table t2 on t1.time >= t2.time
group by t1.id
```

Once you're happy with it, use it as a subselect in an update statement:

```
update table ... from (...) sub where sub.id = table.id
```

(Aside: note that your distance formula doesn't account for acceleration.)

Comment: I was thinking about a solution like this. But this requires N^2 operations while N should be enough... I have something like N=100000 rows...

Comment: I'm not sure it would actually be N operations: for that, you'd need to have the `lag(...) over ...` stored in the table itself (meaning one separate update per row, rather than a huge update for all rows). Or then, you're generating distances using a recursive `with` statement (meaning one new select per row, rather than a huge join). Either way, I suspect both approaches will actually take longer, as they merely hide the N^2 operations under the rug. Try either, though: look into recursive CTE, and window functions. The queries are easy to write.

Comment: look at my update... I'm not able to get it run, but that is the idea